# Постоянный вызов инциализации компонентов

Tags: extjs

Нашел на просторах сети плагин DateRangePicker. На пустой странице с той же версией extjs(6.0.0) плагин работает нормально(как и мой код без плагина), но внутри моего кода при попытке его подключить - идет постоянный вызов инициализации компонентов. Прикрепляю ссылку на участок кода отражающий проблему: http://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1e5p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

я удалил строки 169 и 182 после чего все заработало(не знаю почему)

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/95665)

Comment: Поясняю: в таком виде ответ врядли может быть полезен хоть кому-то. Вы можете описать суть внесенных вами изменений либо вынести это в комментарий.

Comment: Суть в том что что я не понимаю почему контейнер внутри панели вызывает рекурсию.